# Javascript comments for ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, comments

At the moment I use phpDoc style comments when documenting javascript functions, mainly because I am used to the syntax and I feel that phpDoc is a good, comprehensive commenting style to adopt.

One thing it doesn't cover though is Ajax requests (obviously) and I was wondering if there was a set standard for commenting these?  Or if anyone had any suggestions on the best way to comment what the call is doing, what it should return, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to stay with the phpdoc style, I would treat the AJAX call like it's a function, and mainly use the free text description to describe the detail of what's expected. That's what you do with functions, and there's no existing standard for AJAX calls AFAIK, so just do that. Maybe you could start one! Blog about it or something.

Answer (score 1):

[Read this great article](http://dailyjs.com/2011/01/13/framework-part-46/) about javascript code documentation and generating documentation files @ dailyjs.com - it should set you up with what you need.

Comment: cheers! and no worries, it's not about votes it's about sharing love hehe